# JavaScript string concatenation breaks when compressed

Tags: javascript, compression, minify, string-concatenation, django-compressor

I recently decided to start using Django Compressor in a project to automatically concatenate and minify js and css, as well as refresh the cache when they're changed.

The problem I'm having is that there are some scripts that work when not compressed, but after being run through the compressor they break. I've been able to narrow the possibility down to string concatenation. HTML string concatenation in particular.

For example:

```
boldTerm = '<b>' + terms[i] + '</b>';
term = new RegExp(term, 'g');
data = data.replace(term, boldTerm);
```

breaks when compressed. I get a syntax error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

But this works:

```
boldTerm = 'TEST';
term = new RegExp(term, 'g');
data = data.replace(term, boldTerm);
```

Can someone explain:

1. Why it breaks?
2. How I should be writing this so it works when compressed?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the part of the compressed code where the error is being thrown:

```
(jQuery);';term=new RegExp(term,'g');data=data.replace(term,boldTerm);}}
```

It's being being thrown on the 'g' in RegExp(term, g)

I have discovered that this works:

```
boldTerm = '<' + 'b' + '>' + terms[i] + '<' + '/b' + '>';
term = new RegExp(term, 'g');
data = data.replace(term, boldTerm);
```

So that solves part of my problem of just making it work. But the 'why' question still remains.

Things in play:

- jQuery
- Mustache
- Django Compressor (JSmin)

Comment: 1. Why are you overwriting 'term' variable? 2. How does the part of code look like when compressed?

Comment: At what position is the error thrown?

Comment: 1. I have no particular reason for doing that. Since you asked about it, I'll assume I should not do that. 2. See edit above for snippet of compressed code generating error.

Comment: you can overwrite term if you don't need the original string typed term.  
why is there a ' after (jQuery);? that may be your problem. so's syntax highlighting shows you in red, what javaScript really sees of your code (strings are red)...

Comment: @NickHagianis As you can see from the syntax highlighting in your minimized code above, the `(jQuery);';` part is causing the problem. Also, where is the first statement in your minimized code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you aren't exporting RegExp and the compressor is renaming it.